# Getting 400 bad request when i send the data to Rest API using Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework

I am new to `AngularJS` and `Django Rest API`. In my project, I'm trying to upload an image and its title, for that I wrote the following code. I am getting the error:

```
Object {data: Object, status: 400, config: Object, statusText: "Bad Request"}
```

controller:

```
scope.ImageData = [];
    this.saveImages = function(value){
        $scope.images.forEach(function(image){
       angular.forEach(captions, function(value, key){
                if(key == $scope.images.indexOf(image)){
                    if($scope.ImageData.length <= key){
                        $scope.ImageData[key]={
                                'image' : image,
                                'caption' : value,
                                'key'  : key
                     };
                     albumFactory.createImage(slug,$scope.albumData.id,image,value)
                     .then(function(promise){
                        $scope.uploadImage = promise.data;
                     })
                 }           
                }  
            })
        });
    }
```

services:

```
createImage: function(slug,album_id,image,title){
      var fo = new FormData();
      fo.append(image, title);
      return $http.post(api + '/class/' + slug + '/albums/' + album_id + '/photos/' , 
        formData, {
          transformRequest: angular.identity,
          headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
        });
    }  
  }
}
])
```

view:

```
class ImageList(ImageMixin, generics.ListCreateAPIView):
   serializer_class = ImageSerializer
   permission_classes = (ClassPermission,)

   def perform_create(self, serializer):
      album = get_object_or_404(Album,
                              class__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug'),
                              pk=self.kwargs.get('album__pk'))
      serializer.save(album=album)
```

url:

```
url(r'^class/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/albums/(?P<album__pk>\d+)/photos/?$', views.ImageList.as_view())
```

serializer:

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
     model = Photo
     fields = ('image', 'title',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you this for uploading images via ajax:

https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

I have used it and it's very good library for AngularJs.

> To upload images via DRF you should install Pillow, and in serializer declare:

```
image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True, allow_empty_file=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

For image uploads i have faced some issues. I hope this helps you.

It seems that you are sending the image data, and the backend is rejecting that format of data. The image needs to be in basbe64.

Please check this link( stackoverflow.com/questions/28036404/django-rest-framework-upload-image-the-submitted-data-was-not-a-file ) if it is useful.